# Why is an or statement faster than an in statement?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement

In my project, I had to check whether a value was either one of two values. Since I could approach this with an `if or` statement or an `if in` statement, and since I did not know which one of the two would run faster, I ran the following code to check their respective performances:

```
import time
import datetime
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind


def if_in(t):
    bln = False
    for z in range(400):
        if z % 100 == 0: print("test1", z)
        starttime = time.time()
        for x in range(1000000):
            for i in range(5):
                if i in [2, 4]:
                    bln = True
        t.append(time.time() - starttime)
    return t


def if_or(t):
    bln = False
    for z in range(400):
        if z % 100 == 0: print("test2", z)
        starttime = time.time()
        for x in range(1000000):
            for i in range(5):
                if i == 2 or i == 4:
                    bln = True
        t.append(time.time() - starttime)
    return t


st = time.time()

times1 = if_in([])
times2 = if_or([])

t, p = ttest_ind(times1, times2)

print("\nTotal execution time:", str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time() - st)))
t1mean = sum(times1) / len(times1)
t2mean = sum(times2) / len(times2)
print("Test1 mean:", t1mean, "\nTest2 mean:", t2mean)
print("\nT-test p-score:", p)
```

Which printed:

```
Test1 mean: 0.47915725767612455 
Test2 mean: 0.46851890563964843

T-test p-score: 0.001033983121482868
```

The p-value indicates the difference between execution time of the `in` and `or` statement loop to be significant.

Why is this difference? For the 'or' method, I would assume further checking would stop when the first condition is deemed to be true. The same, I again assume, is true for the 'in' method. However, one does run faster than the other.

Additionally, would this hold up for more conditions? E.g. when `i` should be checked to be one of 100 values?

Comment: `if_in()` has overhead of constructing a list object 400*1000000 times, which the other function does not have.

Comment: I would hardly call 468 ms *signficantly* faster than 479 ms. (Also, this indicates that `if_or` is faster than `if_in`.)

Comment: Why do you say "the in statement to take significantly less time to execute than the alternative" when in fact `t2mean` is less than `t1mean`?

Comment: Do the test of running the same function twice. The second run would be faster because some background-magic-initialization was already done.

Comment: And you might consider using a better representation fo rin - with such a small list - list is ok, for a bigger list (guestimate upwards of 10 items) a set is MUCH faster for checking in-ness: `if i in frozenset({2, 4}):` - and put the "declaration" of the set _outside_ the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your observations.

Let us forget for a moment who is "the winner".

The first an most important issue is that you are observing some statistically significant deviation from a mean of value and you are generalizing this as a reflection of the execution speed of some portion of code.
While this may be correct for a particular run of the code, nothing can be said for the approach in general because at that level your measurements are dominated by OS-driven fluctuation.
I am pretty confident (I observed this myself) that multiple runs of this code will give you a different winner for every run.

The second issue is that you are using [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) which is not well suited for benchmarks. You should probably use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), and even then it may not be well suited for measuring such short timings.

The third issue is that your data do not support your conclusions, since `tmean2` associated with `if_or()` is actually smaller than `tmean1` associated with `if_in`.

Note that it is very challenging (and probably irrelevant) to actually measure which is faster between the two options you suggest.

---

Instead, it is interesting to investigate the second question, i.e. for larger repetitions of the pattern `x == y0 or x == y1` etc. is it faster to use `in` on a container?

Let's investigate that (using IPython `%timeit` magic for the timings) for different amount of short-circuiting:

```
def if_or(n, ks, timer=time.perf_counter):
    for _ in range(n):
        for k in ks:
            if k == 0 or k == 1 or k == 2 or k == 3 or k == 4 \
                    or k == 5 or k == 6 or k == 7 or k == 8 or k == 9:
                pass


def if_in_set(n, ks, timer=time.perf_counter):
    for _ in range(n):
        for k in ks:
            if k in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}:
                pass


def if_in_tuple(n, ks, timer=time.perf_counter):
    for _ in range(n):
        for k in ks:
            if k in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9):
                pass


def if_in_list(n, ks, timer=time.perf_counter):
    for _ in range(n):
        for k in ks:
            if k in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
                pass


n = 100000
m = 20
ks = [0] * m
%timeit if_or(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 59 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_set(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 57.6 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_tuple(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 52.4 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_list(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 54.7 ms per loop


ks = list(range(m))
%timeit if_or(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 351 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_set(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 57.6 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_tuple(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 209 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_list(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 214 ms per loop


ks = [-1] * m
%timeit if_or(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 421 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_set(n, ks)
# 10 loop, best of 3: 54.4 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_tuple(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 238 ms per loop
%timeit if_in_list(n, ks)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 237 ms per loop
```

As you can see with enough short circuiting the `or` solution is as fast as `in` on any given container, but in general, using a `set()` is a much better alternative as it proves itself fast (because it has `O(1)` look-up time, compared to `tuple` or `list` that have `O(N)` look-up time) and independent of the short-circuiting bet.

---

Finally, to get some indication of why `or` is slower, let's disassemble `if_or()` and `if_in_set()` using `dis`:

- `if_or()`

```
import dis


dis.dis(if_or)
```

```
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP             110 (to 112)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                98 (to 110)
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (_)

  3          14 SETUP_LOOP              92 (to 108)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (ks)
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   20 FOR_ITER                84 (to 106)
             22 STORE_FAST               4 (k)

  4          24 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             28 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             30 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             32 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             34 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             36 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             40 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             42 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             44 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             46 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             48 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             50 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             52 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             54 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             56 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             58 LOAD_CONST               5 (4)
             60 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             62 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             64 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             66 LOAD_CONST               6 (5)
             68 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             70 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             72 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             74 LOAD_CONST               7 (6)
             76 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             78 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             80 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             82 LOAD_CONST               8 (7)
             84 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             86 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             88 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             90 LOAD_CONST               9 (8)
             92 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             94 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             96 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             98 LOAD_CONST              10 (9)
            100 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
            102 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

  5         104 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
        >>  106 POP_BLOCK
        >>  108 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>  110 POP_BLOCK
        >>  112 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            114 RETURN_VALUE
```

- `if_in_set()`

```
import dis


dis.dis(if_in_set)
```

```
  9           0 SETUP_LOOP              38 (to 40)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                26 (to 38)
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (_)

 10          14 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 36)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (ks)
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   20 FOR_ITER                12 (to 34)
             22 STORE_FAST               4 (k)

 11          24 LOAD_FAST                4 (k)
             26 LOAD_CONST              11 (frozenset({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}))
             28 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             30 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

 12          32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   36 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   38 POP_BLOCK
        >>   40 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             42 RETURN_VALUE
```

there you can see that the lengthy third block of `if_or()` with multiple relatively expensive `COMPARE_OP` calls is replaced by a single `COMPARE_OP` call.
The container is being frozen by the optimization mechanisms of Python.

Comment: This is an excellent answer: both a critical breakdown of my method followed by an in-depth exploration of the two methods. I could not have asked for more!